# how can I find a middle of an interpolation algorithme

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, intellij-idea

I had a problem with this search algorithm, when the target value being the last element in the list, the middle becomes ZERO, where it must be 8, I calculated that by myself and I got 8, but when I do debug, I found zero again, if you can help, please feel free
this is the code :

```
class InterpolationSearch {
    companion object{

        fun Interpolation(list : List<Int> , Target_value : Int ){

        var Lo = 0
        var Hi = list.lastIndex

        while (Lo <= Hi || list[Lo] <= list[Hi]){

            var mid = Lo + ((Hi - Lo) / (list[Hi] - list[Lo])) * (Target_value - list[Lo]) // this is the middle.

            if (list[mid] == Target_value){
                println("success, target found in $mid")
                break
            }else if(list[mid] < Target_value){
                Lo = mid + 1
            }else if (list[mid] > Target_value){
                Hi = mid -1
            }
        }
        if (Lo >= Hi || list[Lo] >= list[Hi]){
            println("failure, target not found")
        }
      }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val matrix = listOf<Int>( 32 , 33 , 54 , 1102 , 1124 , 1144 , 1150 , 1203 ,1222 )
    try {
        InterpolationSearch.Interpolation(matrix , 1222)
    }catch (e : ArithmeticException){
        println("SOMETHING DIVIDED BY ZERO :/")
    }
}
```

Comment: As all values in the array are distinct, the division by zero occurs because Hi=Lo, which should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

set `mid = Lo` in case when `Lo == Hi`